# In Google Sheets, how do I add an extra leading zero to a list of numbers that are all written as #345 for example?

Tags: google-sheets

Formatting issue- my spreadsheet had numbers from #001 up to #850, but a new addition has taken the highest value past #1000, so now all of my old values need to change to four digit numbers. Is there any easy way to do this? The # is stopping me from using a custom number format and I don't know how to quickly remove all the # symbols.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you have all 999 numbers from #001 to #999, one per row. Clear all the cells with incorrect values. In the first empty cell, paste the formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("#" & TEXT(ROW(1:999), "0000"))
```

Then for good measure, copy all those cells, and from the menus choose Edit → Paste special → Values only. This will change those cells from live formula output to literal strings—important if data will ever be rearranged.

The formula just tells Sheets

`ROW(1:999)` ← Start with this is a quick way to generate 999 numbers.
`=ARRAYFORMULA(…)` …now, for that whole array of 999 values,
`"#" &`  …output a text string with a number sign before…
`TEXT( … , "0000")` …the number from earlier, with leading zeroes to always be four digits.

Answer (score 0):

#### A Forgiving Formula

1. Order of source data doesn't matter
2. It doesn't matter if the numbers are in a sequence or random
3. It doesn't matter if there are empty cells
4. Source data can be any number of digits with or without a hash mark
5. Don't need to know the actual count of rows or strings.
   The example below is applied to all rows (except row 1) in column A if they are not blank: `A2:A<>""`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"",
   "#" & TEXT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A, "#",)), "000#"),
   IFERROR(1/0)))
```

Some *"irregular"* values and typos were added in red font to the sample table below to illustrate how they are handled by the formula.

[image]